# how to handle the return of a javascript function with nested Parse.Promises inside

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, promise

I have this function:

```
function doCalculateStopBefore(thisD, lastD){

  thisD.attributes.start.fetch().then(function(){
    return lastD.attributes.end.fetch();
  }).then(function(){
    // calculate some stuff here using thisD.attributes.start and lastD.attributes.stop

    thisD.set('property', value); // <--- important. update thisD! 
  });
  return thisD; // < --- !!! this line doesn't want for the promises chain! 
}
```

`thisD` and `lastD` are `Parse.Objects`. I need to fetch this 2 fields (pointers to another parse Class), then calculate some stuff with this values and update `thisD`. THEN I want to finish the function...

the function is going to be called in a `_.each loop` like this:

```
_.each(myCollection.models,function(thisD,index){
if (index == 0){
      // first entry of user
      // do not do anything.
    } else{
      //thisD = doCalculateStopBefore(thisD,myCollection.models[index-1]);
           // above is how I had it before. 
           // below is my implementation of Troy's reply: 
      doCalculateStopBefore(thisD,myCollection.models[index-1]).then(function(thisD) {
        console.log(thisD.attributes);
        thisDrive = thisD;
      }) 
    }

    promises.push(thisD.save());
  });
```

how can I put the return inside the last then, or chaining it somehow?

Comment: Why not just return the promise?

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the Promise from your first fetch() in doCalculateStopBefore() and add a then() to it to capture the updated value.  See the updated code below.

```
function doCalculateStopBefore(thisD, lastD){
    return thisD.attributes.start.fetch().then(function(){
        return lastD.attributes.end.fetch();
    }).then(function(){
        // calculate some stuff here using thisD.attributes.start
        // and lastD.attributes.stop

        thisD.set('property', value); // <--- important. update thisD! 
        return thisD;
    });
}
```

You can call this in a loop as below using Parse.Promises.when() to coordinate all the saves.

```
var promises = [];

_.each(myCollection.models, function(thisD, index) {
    if (index == 0) {
        // first entry of user
        // do not do anything.
    } else {
        promises.push(doCalculateStopBefore(thisD,myCollection.models[index-1]).then(function(thisD) {
            console.log(thisD.attributes);
            thisDrive = thisD;
            return thisD.save();
        }));
    }
});

Parse.Promise.when(promises).then(function() {
    console.log("done");
});
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for you answer. I see, you took the promise outside of the function, it it's call. The problem now is how to tell the _.each loop to wait for the promise! notice that the each loop is inside another promise, and I fill an array with promises. Do you have a solution for that? thanks.

Comment: I updated it to do as you wanted, let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi You wrote I need to return a promise in the function. Am I returning a promise by returning `thisD` inside the last then? I tried it, and the function isn't returning a promise, so that the `then` after the function call will fail.